# SQLite: identify page type just from its bytes?

Tags: sqlite, database-design

From https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html it looks like there are 9 types of pages in a SQLite database:

- The lock-byte page
- A freelist trunk page
- A freelist leaf page
- A table b-tree interior page
- A table b-tree leaf page
- An index b-tree interior page
- An index b-tree leaf page
- A payload overflow page
- A pointer map page

Given just the bytes of a single page, is it possible to identify its type?

I'm actually leaning to *no*, it's not possible. For example since for an overflow page

> The first four bytes of each overflow page are a big-endian integer which is the page number of the next page in the chain

and this means that certain overflow pages could look like a b-tree page based on its first byte:

> The one-byte flag at offset 0 indicating the b-tree page type.
>
> - A value of 2 (0x02) means the page is an interior index b-tree page.
> - A value of 5 (0x05) means the page is an interior table b-tree page.
> - A value of 10 (0x0a) means the page is a leaf index b-tree page.
> - A value of 13 (0x0d) means the page is a leaf table b-tree page.

But... I'm hoping I've overlooked something. (For example, is it possible to look at some byte(s) other than the first to determine the type?)

Comment: I think you have answered your own question.

Comment: @user965972 I've slightly edited the question to hopefully show that I haven't completely answered the question. I'm reaching a bit, I know. But, if you don't ask...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think it’s possible from what I know about the file format thus far. My reasoning:

1. It’s only possible if the first 13 pages are not an overflow page from your summary.
2. Overflow pages are used if the data exceeds the embedded payload limit on a leaf page.
3. The smallest table is just a single leaf page as its root page.
4. The smallest leaf page is a single row.
5. Page 1 is used for the header and the master table.

Thus the smallest database has a master table (page 1), with a single row in its only table (page 2). From the moment that one row overflows the maximum payload fraction, an overflow page is created. That would then be page 3.